# Need direction: .setObject vs .setString and saving column info to database from GUI

Tags: java, sql, jdbc

My code has much repetition so i will just shorthand those parts. I do not know what is the problem with my code as no errors are reported.. just nothing happens.

I am using Netbeans GUI, jdbc and MS SQL. My connection is solid with
preparedstatment = pst
connection = conn
etc.

My aim here is to save text and columns into a single resultset table in SQL.

The code is activated by private void in an action:

```
 private void INSERT1saveCustomers() {
    int index=1;
    int count = jTable1.getRowCount();

    for(int i=0;i<count;i++){

        SET0 = new Object[1][count];
        SET0[0][i] = txtTestiNIMI1.getText(); }
```

This is repeated for all objects named SET. It is followed by defining SAVE in a similar fashion

```
SAVE = new Object[1][count];  
SAVE[0][i] = jTable1.getModel().getValueAt(i,0);
```

Which i then lead into my two SQL queries

```
String sqla1 = "INSERT INTO MIT(MTY_KOD,MTY_TYY,MTY_ALU,MTY_PARA1,MTY_PARA2,MTY_TOL,MTY_KAN) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  try{
    pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqla1);

   pst.setObject(1, SET0);
   pst.setObject(2, SET2);
   pst.setObject(3, SET1);
   pst.setObject(4, SAVE);
   pst.setObject(5, SAVE3);
   pst.setObject(6, SAVE5);
   pst.setObject(7, SET3);
   rs = pst.executeQuery();
   }

catch(Exception e){}


 String sqlb1 = "INSERT INTO TEST(TET_KOD,TET_LUK,TET_ARE,TET_YRE,TET_PVF,TET_TEMP,TET_HUM,TET_DATE, TET_VIR, TET_ERR) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
 try{
       pst = conn.prepareStatement(sqlb1);

   pst.setObject(1, SET0);
   pst.setObject(2, SAVE4);
   pst.setObject(3, SAVE6);
   pst.setObject(4, SAVE7);
   pst.setObject(5, SET4);
   pst.setObject(6, SET5);
   pst.setObject(7, SET6);
   pst.setObject(8, SET2);
   pst.setObject(9, SAVE8);
   pst.setObject(10, SET7);
   rs = pst.executeQuery();
   }

catch(Exception e){}

    }
```

No errors are reported... And yes i know that Exception e is there currently but it twas not always so :P

the information just never saves. I have also tried using pst.setString(x,SET.toString()) with the same issue so, I do not know from where to adress the issue. Any help would be appreciated... thank you!

Comment: i guess i should be using byte arrays but i am re-researching the topic

Answer (score 1):

To insert, update or delete data, you must use `statement.executeUpdate()`.

And please: don't swallow exceptions. This is what makes you think nothing happens. Something happens: an exception is thrown, but you choose to ignore it with:

```
catch (Exception e){}
```

If you don't know how to handle an exception in this method, then make the method throw is:

```
public void foo() throws SQLException
```

or at least, catch it but rethrow it wrapped into a runtime exception:

```
catch (SQLException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Comment: As it turns out there were two issues that were hiding in the exception:

 com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The conversion from UNKOWN to UNKNOWN is unsupported

and my query doesnt change for some reason 

 INSERT INTO TEST(TET_KOD,TET_LUK,TET_ARE,TET_YRE,TET_PVF,TET_TEMP,TET_HUM,TET_DATE, TET_VIR, TET_ERR) values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)

Thusfar i havent had any issues using query instead of update... they share syntax i think but I will try rewriting